# NodeJS app cannot fetch assets - 404

Tags: node.js

I have the right path under the root directory, all of my assets are 404 though. Also this is supposed to be the root.

Console:

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular/client/js/1.3.0/angular-animate.js 
sheltered-beach-2553.herokuapp.com/:19 GET https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax//client/libs/animate.css/3.3.0/animate.min.css 
sheltered-beach-2553.herokuapp.com/:63 GET https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4//client/js/bootstrap.js 
sheltered-beach-2553.herokuapp.com/:68 GET https://sheltered-beach-2553.herokuapp.com/client/libs/angular-route/angular-route.min.js 
sheltered-beach-2553.herokuapp.com/:20 GET https://sheltered-beach-2553.herokuapp.com/css/custom.css 404 (Not Found)
sheltered-beach-2553.herokuapp.com/:70 GET https://sheltered-beach-2553.herokuapp.com/client/libs/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js 
sheltered-beach-2553.herokuapp.com/:71 GET https://sheltered-beach-2553.herokuapp.com/client/libs/angular-socket-io/socket.js 
sheltered-beach-2553.herokuapp.com/:69 GET https://sheltered-beach-2553.herokuapp.com/client/libs/angular-resource/angular-resource.js
```

JS:

As you can see I've used both `../` and  as a prefix:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../client/js/app.js"></script>

<!--Main Controllers-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="client/js/controllers/homeController.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="client/js/controllers/navController.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../client/js/controllers/aboutController.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../client/js/controllers/projectsController.js"></script>

<!--Project Controllers-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/client/js/controllers/projects/customerApiController.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/client/js/controllers/projects/chatController.js"></script>
You can check out the whole output of my console over here:
    https://sheltered-beach-2553.herokuapp.com/
```

Comment: For starters, please post some code so we can see what's wrong with your inside URLs. Then, a quick test on https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax//client/libs/angular/client/js/1.3.0/angular-animate.js shows that the address does not exist.

Comment: yes, the one you pointed out is a bug, but still the rest aren't there. Why? I'll mod my question to include some code now.